# Django, query for related field: related field exists which meet conditions

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Suppose you have Question and Answer model.

I want questions that have answers which are neither deleted nor being reviewed.
(I want questions that would return True for the following function.)

```
def has_active_answer(self):
   return self.answers.not_deleted().filter(is_inreview=False).exists()


not_deleted() === filter(deleted=False) # if that makes difference
```

Comment: @falsetru: exists() 's return type is boolean?

Comment: Yes, `exists()` returns True or False.

Comment: ah, I want queryset results, or question objects at least.

Comment: Related, with some explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30948277/2810305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the model is `Question` and it has `answers` field:

```
Question.objects.filter(answers__deleted=False, answers__is_inreview=False)
```

Comment: it's really that simple? awesome

Comment: @eugene, Yes, you can use related model's field using `related_model__field=blah` keyword argument.

Comment: shoot, I just realize my not_deleted() is more complex.      `def not_deleted(self):
         return self.filter(Q(main_post__isnull=True) | Q(main_post__deleted=False))` ...

Comment: @eugene, Update the conditino accordingly: `Question.objects.filter((Q(main_post__isnull=True) | Q(main_post__deleted=False)) & Q(answers__deleted=False) & Q(answers__is_inreview=False))`

Comment: it's Q(answers__main_post__isnull=True) isn't it?

Comment: @eugene, It depends on where the `main_post` field belong.  If it's the field of `answers`, yes it is. By the way `main_post__isnull=True` can be expressed as `main_post=None`.

Comment: gee.. Are you from seoul? korean speaker with 119k? .. wonder what you make with your programming knowledge.. (couldn't find a way to private message..)

Comment: @eugene, Yes, I am a Korean in Seoul. About programming knowledge, I got it from book, internet, code from others ...

Comment: gee, I am a Korean as well. We should meet up sometime, I'd like to buy a coffee or lunch whatever for your help (you answered many of my questions) if you don't mind.