# Django queryset on related field with multiple constraints

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # ... some fields

class Tag(models.Model):
    # ... some fields

class UserTag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='tags')
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name='users')
    date_removed = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I lets say I want to get all the users that have a given tag that has not yet been removed (ie date_removed=None). If I didn't have to worry about the date_removed constraint, I could do:

```
User.objects.filter(tags__tag=given_tag)
```

But I want to get all users who have that given tag **and** have the tag without a date_removed on it. Is there an easy way in Django to get that in a single queryset? And assume I have millions of Users, so getting any sort of list of User IDs and keeping it in memory is not practical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `filter()` call can include multiple constraints:

```
User.objects.filter(tags__tag=given_tag, tags__date_removed=None)
```

When they match, they will both match to the *same* `Tag`, not two possibly different ones.

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) on spanning multi-valued relationships;
in particular, the difference between `filter(a, b)` and `filter(a).filter(b)`.

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for -- just couldn't find it in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: The (very important) fact that `filter(a, b)` and `filter(a).filter(b)` can be different is one of the most surprising features of Django. Easy to overlook when you first read the documentation, even if you think you are doing it thoroughly.